# Vuejs proxy not working with webpack template

Tags: webpack, proxy, vue.js, cors, vuejs2

I am developing a vuejs project with the [webpack](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/) template on localhost i.e. url: `localhost:8080` but I have an express server running in `https://foo.bar.com`

In the past, I have been making a direct request to the express server by disabling CORS, but now I am trying to make a request via proxy.

According to this [API Proxying During Development](https://vuejs-templates.github.io/webpack/proxy.html) I have added the following to my `config/index.js`

```
proxyTable: {
  // proxy all requests starting with /api to jsonplaceholder
  '/': {
  target: 'https://foo.bar.com',
  changeOrigin: true,
  pathRewrite: {
  '^/': ''
  }
}
```

And in my login page `components/login.vue`

I have something like this:

```
...
methods: {
  Login(){
     // trying 3 times with different urls
    api.request('post', 'login', {email, password}).then().catch()
    api.request('post', '/login', {email, password}).then().catch()
    api.request('post', 'https://foo.bar.com/login', {email, password}).then().catch()
  }   
}
```

But I get an error like this:

`Failed to load https://foo.bar.com/login: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.`

Comment: CORS is not disabled.. cross verify your code

Comment: Obviously it is not disabled. The question is how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enable CORS in your express application as follows

Install CORS package from npm

```
$ npm install cors
```

Enable in your express application like below code

```
var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()

app.use(cors())

app.get('/api/message', function (req, res, next) {
  res.json({msg: 'This is CORS-enabled for all origins!'})
})
```

For more information to customize cors package as your need,  refer https://github.com/expressjs/cors